Update duplicated IDs
I'm trying to figure a way of updating a bunch of duplicated values.
The database schema looks like this:
ID | EntryId | Description | Category
1 | test1 | test description | fault
2 | test1 | test description | fault
3 | test1 | test description | fault
4 | test2 | test description | fault
5 | test2 | test description | fault
6 | test3 | test description | fault
7 | test4 | test description | fault
8 | test5 | test description | fault
9 | test5 | test description | fault
10 | test5 | test description | fault
11 | test6 | test description | fault
12 | test6 | test description | fault
... more entries below ...

I need to have a sql script to append an alphabet to the duplicated EntryId in the form of test1a, test1b, test1c, test2a, test2b, test5a, test5b, test5c, test6a, test6b and for any other duplicated EntryId and update the new values into the database.
Have tried with the following script below but as I'm not really trained in sql scripting, have come here to request for help.
SELECT ID, EntryId
, CONCAT( EntryId, CHAR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EntryId ASC)) + 96) ) AS NewEntryId
FROM table
WHERE EntryId
IN 
(   SELECT EntryId
    FROM table
    GROUP BY EntryId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
)

Thank you in advance!

You have to PARTITION BY EntryId too, and ask yourself what if more than 26 duplicates... and if do you really want to add something if there is only 1....

you can use a combination of SQL queries to identify duplicated EntryId values and then update them with appended alphabets. Below is an example SQL script that accomplishes this task:
    -- Update duplicated EntryId values with appended alphabets
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        EntryId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntryId ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum,
        CHAR(96 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntryId ORDER BY ID)) AS Alphabet
    FROM 
        YourTableName
)
UPDATE CTE
SET EntryId = CONCAT(EntryId, Alphabet)
WHERE CTE.RowNum > 1;

Replace YourTableName with the actual name of your table. This script identifies duplicated EntryId values, assigns alphabets to them based on their occurrence, and then updates the EntryId column with the new values.
You can also use "cast" methods. kindly prefer this for this method as I can't write everything here

You don't need the self-join, you can do UPDATE CTE directly.
